# Using "mutate_each" from the dplyr-library

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to use the same function on different variables. However, I don't know how exactly this can be done with `dplyr-library` in R.

I'd like to change the values of 6 variable to `NA` if they have the value "`-8`".
This is what I came up with (it works but it looks clumsy):

```
bfs_data %>%
  
  select(musul_sty_01,
         musul_sty_02,
         musul_sty_03,
         musul_sty_04,
         musul_sty_05,
         musul_sty_06) %>%
  mutate(
    musul_sty_01 = na_if(musul_sty_01,"-8"),
    musul_sty_02 = na_if(musul_sty_02,"-8"),
    musul_sty_03 = na_if(musul_sty_03,"-8"),
    musul_sty_04 = na_if(musul_sty_04,"-8"),
    musul_sty_05 = na_if(musul_sty_05,"-8"),
    musul_sty_06 = na_if(musul_sty_06,"-8")
  )
```

So I tried to use `mutate_each` like this:

```
sty_muslim <- bfs_data %>%
  select(musul_sty_01,
         musul_sty_02,
         musul_sty_03,
         musul_sty_04,
         musul_sty_05,
         musul_sty_06) %>%
  mutate_each(
    funs(na_if("-8")),
    musul_sty_01,
    musul_sty_02,
    musul_sty_03,
    musul_sty_04,
    musul_sty_05,
    musul_sty_06
  )
```

It does not work and I dont know why. I get this error:

> check_length(y, x, fmt_args("y"), glue("same as {fmt_args(~x)}")) :
> Argument "x" fehlt (ohne Standardwert)

I have never used `mutate_each` before so I very appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the new version of `dplyr` you can use `across()` like this (Not tested as no data was shared):

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
newdata <- bfs_data %>% mutate(across(musul_sty_01:musul_sty_06,~ifelse(.=='-8',NA,.)))
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this in base R, you can select the columns that you want to change using column names, numbers or pattern in their name. From the post it seems you are trying to change `-8` to `NA` for columns that have `'musul_sty_'` in it. We can use `grep` to select columns here.

For example, if your dataframe is :

```
bfs_data <- data.frame(a = 1:4, musul_sty_01 = c(-8, 2, 3, 4), 
                       musul_sty_02 = c(-2, 3, -8, 2))
bfs_data
#  a musul_sty_01 musul_sty_02
#1 1           -8           -2
#2 2            2            3
#3 3            3           -8
#4 4            4            2
```

With `grep` we select the column and then replace the -8 value with `NA`.

```
cols <- grep('musul_sty_', names(bfs_data))
bfs_data[cols][bfs_data[cols] == -8] <- NA

#  a musul_sty_01 musul_sty_02
#1 1           NA           -2
#2 2            2            3
#3 3            3           NA
#4 4            4            2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table` methods

```
library(data.table)
setDT(bfs_data)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) 
     fifelse( x == -8, NA_real_, x)), .SDcols = patterns('musul_sty_')]
#   musul_sty_01 musul_sty_02
#1:           NA           -2
#2:            2            3
#3:            3           NA
#4:            4            2
```

#### data

```
bfs_data <- data.frame(a = 1:4, musul_sty_01 = c(-8, 2, 3, 4), 
                   musul_sty_02 = c(-2, 3, -8, 2))
```